# Issue: TypeScript not finding the declaration file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have two files in /src/models/ they are User.ts and User.d.ts. I am trying to build a class in User and then have a interface declaration for an object I use in User.d.ts. I thought User.ts would be able to use the interface automatically because typescript parses all the d.ts files? Is there something wrong with the config? Or maybe I am just not understanding the concept?

The Error I get is in the User.d.ts file:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: src/models/User.d.ts.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided
```

User.ts:

```
class User {
  private id: number;

  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  static create(userData: UserData): User | undefined {
    return undefined;
  }

  getId(): number {
    return this.id;
  }
}

export default User;
```

UserData.d.ts:

```
interface UserData {
  id?: number;
  gmail?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  loginIP?: string;
  secureKey?: string;
  imgFileName?: string; // file name of the users profile image
  lastUpdate?: string;
  createDate?: string;
}
```

User.ts is having an issue finding UserData and I can't seem to use it in the file.
My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["/src/**/*.ts", "**/src/**/*.ts", "**/__tests__/**/*.ts"]
}
```

My .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  settings: {
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {},
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': [2, { devDependencies: ['**/*.test.tsx', '**/*.test.ts'] }],
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': [2, 2],
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
        mjs: 'never',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Where am I off? Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: The idea of type definition (filename.d.ts) is when you want types to be available to the entire project. Maybe you are using some library that doesn't have its types(i.e. @types/lib-name). In your case, you can just define a file with 'ts' only on can be exported and imported easily without going into type definition complexities. If you still want to use type definition define 'typeRoots' in tsconfig.json file. You can read more about it https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots

Comment: The typeRoots solution works. I was trying to organize the types. I've seen monolothic declaration of types index.d.ts that belonged to different modules and it's a pain to go through. Seems like maybe then just declaring it within the .ts file that it belongs to is the better way then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### TLDR

> Configure `typeRoots` config in `tsconfig.json`

#### Answer 1

The way I see it, you can use `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`.
This config:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
    ...
 },
```

---

### Answer 2

How about fix `include` options with `"/src/**/*.d.ts"`

```
"include": ["/src/**/*.ts", "**/src/**/*.ts", "**/__tests__/**/*.ts",  "/src/**/*.d.ts"]
```

#### Reference

1. [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: tried it, and reloaded vscode just incase no go. the error is in the .d.ts file arsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: src/models/User.d.ts.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.eslint

Comment: Oh, I see, I am going to struggle for you!

Comment: Been struggling all day here pal.

Comment: How about fix `include` config with `/src/**/*.d.ts` in `tsconfig.json` 
Have you ever been try it?

Comment: i was trying "./src/models/*.ts". let me try that one.

Comment: Is it worked? But, I saw the comment and I agree .d.ts is just for library declaration.
And it is right to use just `ts` for interface

Comment: Ok, so after playing around and trying to get typeRoots to work i got it eventually. I had to add a baseUrl key to the compilerOptions "baseUrl": ".",. And i changed my include to be "include": ["src/", "__tests__/"]. Seems to be working ts nor eslint screaming and I can see the type in the test file. Also had to add node_modules/@types to the typeRoots aswell. "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/**/*.d.ts"]. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would personally recommend Answer 2 using includes, because by setting typeRoots you will lose the automatic resolution of @types node modules. In a standard repo you can easily add that behavior back in, but in a mono repo there isn't currently a way to tell TS to keep that default behavior on top of your typeRoots.